# Why is the Capitalization delayed in this JavaFx App when using change listener?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, observable

I have this simple app on JavaFx that creates lazy instanziators for javafx beans, the app is entirely gui, it only has an fxml and main class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.SuperLazyfxController">
   <children>
      <StackPane layoutX="3.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="594.0">
         <children>
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#0f5694" height="392.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="594.0" />
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="344.0" prefWidth="594.0">
               <children>
                  <VBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="59.0" prefHeight="144.0" prefWidth="459.0" spacing="10.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="134.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="38.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="67.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="59.0">
                     <children>
                        <HBox prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="537.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="262.0" text="Accesibilidad Property :" textFill="#ae9c3e">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="Ebrima Bold" size="18.0" />
                                 </font>
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets right="10.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin>
                              </Label>
                              <TextField fx:id="accesib" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="277.0" />
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="537.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="262.0" text="TipoProperty" textFill="#ae9c3e">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="Ebrima Bold" size="18.0" />
                                 </font>
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets right="10.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin>
                              </Label>
                              <TextField fx:id="Tipo" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="277.0" />
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="537.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="261.0" text="Nombre Property :" textFill="#ae9c3e">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="Ebrima Bold" size="18.0" />
                                 </font>
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets right="10.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin>
                              </Label>
                              <TextField fx:id="nombre" onKeyReleased="#mayusculas" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="277.0" />
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="537.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="261.0" text="Shadowfield type" textFill="#ae9c3e">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="Ebrima Bold" size="18.0" />
                                 </font>
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets right="10.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin>
                              </Label>
                              <TextField fx:id="tiposhadow" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="277.0" />
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Clean" text="Clean" textFill="#907c39">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
                  <TextArea fx:id="area" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="267.0" prefHeight="118.0" prefWidth="563.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="16.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="267.0" />
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="139.0" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="321.0" text="Super-Lazy Insta JavaFX" textFill="RED" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="338.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="139.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="134.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="25.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here the main class:

```
package app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SuperLazyfx.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Lazy-instanziatior");
        stage.show();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

and here is the controller class

```
package app;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class SuperLazyfxController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField Tipo;
    @FXML
    private TextField nombre;
    @FXML
    private TextField tiposhadow;
    @FXML
    private TextField accesib;
    @FXML
    private TextArea area;

    private StringBinding sbind;
    private StringProperty nombreMayus = new SimpleStringProperty("Nombrevar");
    private StringProperty nombreMin = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        sbind = new StringBinding() {

            {
                super.bind(Tipo.textProperty(), nombre.textProperty(), tiposhadow.textProperty(), accesib.textProperty());
            }

            @Override
            protected String computeValue() {

                return accesib.textProperty().get() + " " + Tipo.textProperty().get() + " " + nombre.textProperty().get() + ";\n"
                        + accesib.textProperty().get() + " " + tiposhadow.textProperty().get() + " _" + nombre.textProperty().get() + ";\n\n"

                        + "public " + tiposhadow.textProperty().get() + " get" + nombreMayus.get() + nombreMin.get()+"(){"
                        + "\n\t return ("+nombre.textProperty().get()+" ==null)? _"+nombre.textProperty().get()+": "+nombre.textProperty().get()+".get();\n"
                        +"}\n\n"

                        + "public void set"+ nombreMayus.get() + nombreMin.get()+"("+tiposhadow.textProperty().get()+" "+nombre.textProperty().get()+"){"
                        + "\t\nif(this."+nombre.textProperty().get()+"==null){\n"
                        + "\t_"+nombre.textProperty().get()+"="+nombre.textProperty().get()+";\n"
                        + "\t} else{\n"
                        + "\tthis."+nombre.textProperty().get()+".set("+nombre.textProperty().get()+");\n"
                        + "\t}\n"
                        + "}\n\n"

                        + "public "+ Tipo.textProperty().get()+" "+nombre.textProperty().get()+"Property(){\n"
                        + "\treturn ("+nombre.textProperty().get()+"== null)? "+nombre.textProperty().get()+"= new Simple"+Tipo.textProperty().get()+"(this,\""+nombre.textProperty().get()+"\", _"+nombre.textProperty().get()+"): "+nombre.textProperty().get()+";\n"
                        + "}"
                        ;
            }
        };

        area.textProperty().bind(sbind);

    }

    @FXML
    private void mayusculas(KeyEvent event) {
        nombre.textProperty().addListener((ov, oldV, newV) -> {
            if (!(nombre.textProperty().get().isEmpty())) {
                nombreMayus.set(newV.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
            } else {
                nombreMayus.set("Nombrevar");
            }
        });
        nombre.textProperty().addListener((ov, oldV, newV) -> {
            if (!(nombre.textProperty().get().isEmpty())) {
                nombreMin.set(newV.substring(1));
            } else {
                nombreMin.set("");
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    private void Clean(ActionEvent event) {
        Tipo.textProperty().set("");
        nombre.textProperty().set("");
        tiposhadow.textProperty().set("");
        accesib.textProperty().set("");
    }


}
```

The problem falls here:

```
@FXML
    private void mayusculas(KeyEvent event) {
        nombre.textProperty().addListener((ov, oldV, newV) -> {
            if (!(nombre.textProperty().get().isEmpty())) {
                nombreMayus.set(newV.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
            } else {
                nombreMayus.set("Nombrevar");
            }
        });
        nombre.textProperty().addListener((ov, oldV, newV) -> {
            if (!(nombre.textProperty().get().isEmpty())) {
                nombreMin.set(newV.substring(1));
            } else {
                nombreMin.set("");
            }
        });
    }
```

And here:

```
+ "public void set"+ nombreMayus.get() + nombreMin.get()+"("+tiposhadow.textProperty().get()+" "+nombre.textProperty().get()+"){"
```

the nombreMayus.get() shows, when the first letter is typed "Nombrevar" on the Text Area while when the second one is typed it shows the first letter you see!!! It is delayed

Comment: I would presume it has to do with the fact that `if (!(nombre.textProperty().get().isEmpty())) {` when you press the first letter, the textProperty IS empty and once you press the second letter it is no longer empty. perhaps you need to delay it until after keyReleased, purely as the keyEvent logs all key results (up and down) and the first result will be keyDown so it see it as empty as the key goes down.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to add change listener in `onKeyReleased()` event. This way you are adding a brand new listener every single time the user keys something on the keyboard.

You can probably do this:

```
nombreMayus.bind(() -> nombre.getText().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(), nombre.textProperty());
nombreMin.bind(() -> nombre.getText().substring(1), nombre.textProperty());
```